# woocommerce_thankyou hook triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In the woocommerce_thankyou hook, I added some jQuery code to open a static URL in a new tab. But it will open the URL multiple times. Here is the code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_carecredit');
function woocommerce_thankyou_carecredit($order_id){
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $data = $order->get_data();
        if($data['payment_method'] == 'cod){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var url = "https://www.carecredit.com/go/232CND/";
            window.open(url, '_blank');});
            </script>';
        }
}
```

I want to understand what I am doing wrong. Is there anyone who can help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you've figured this out, but you're missing a quote in this line around 'cod': `if($data['payment_method'] == 'cod)`. Would add some type of error log to see how many times this is run. maybe something like`error_log(print_r($order_id, true));`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook for that, use instead `wp_footer` hook like:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'wc_thankyou_carecredit_js' );
function wc_thankyou_carecredit_js(){
    global $wp;
    // Only on thankyou page
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && is_checkout() ) || ! isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ) return;

    $order_id    = intval($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
    $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object

    if ( $order && $order->get_payment_method() === 'cod' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function(){
        const url = "https://www.carecredit.com/go/232CND/";
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

It should better work.